# Photoshop gradient overlay isn't transparent

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, gradient

I wanted to make a gradient from black to transparent but it doesn't work.

I have a red layer as a background and a rectangle with a gradient overlay. The top-right corner has opacity set to 0 but instead of showing a black to transparent gradient, it still shows a white to black gradient.

Why is it not working?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though you have applied a black to transparent gradient, via the layer effects, to your top layer, I can see that the layer itself is still filled with white.

**Set the fill of the top layer to 0%**

Another tip for you: **Change both colors of your gradient to black**, then adjust the opacity. Leaving the gradient as a Black > White one will mean that the colors between the two points are not only black, but varying shades from black to white and therefore not a true black to transparent gradient

Here you can see what you have right now: a white layer with a black > transparent gradient style applied to it.  As you can see, the fill color of the layer is still white

[image]

You need to decrease the fill of the layer to 0%, which will make the layer transparent, allowing your transparent gradient to work

[image]

A simple break-down:

- **Fill** is the base upon which your layer styles are applied.  No matter what styles or effects you add, the fill is still underneath it all. ***Change this to affect only the fill of the layer and leave your styles intact***
- **Opacity** affects the entire layer (fill and styles).  ***Change this to decrease the opacity of everything on the layer***

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the explanatino sir! you was right! not all heros wear cape

Comment: @D4rWiNS Another tip for you: **Change both colors of your gradient to black, then adjust the opacity**.  Leaving the gradient as a Black > White one will mean that the colors between the two points are not only black, but varying shades from black to white and therefore not a true black to transparent gradient